# health-check-grace-period-seconds override the default or apply the value only for the command?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, amazon-elb

I have ECS containers running. when I run this command:

```
aws ecs update-service --region us-east-1 --cluster my-cluster --service my-service --force-new-deployment
```

it take about 5 minutes to load balancer to replace the container. and another 5 minutes to shutdown the old container.

I want to make it immediately without change the any configuration.

So I find the option `health-check-grace-period-seconds` [in the docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ecs/update-service.html):

> The period of time, in seconds, that the Amazon ECS service scheduler
> should ignore unhealthy Elastic Load Balancing target health checks
> after a task has first started. This is only valid if your service is
> configured to use a load balancer. If your service's tasks take a
> while to start and respond to Elastic Load Balancing health checks,
> you can specify a health check grace period of up to 2,147,483,647
> seconds. During that time, the Amazon ECS service scheduler ignores
> the Elastic Load Balancing health check status. This grace period can
> prevent the ECS service scheduler from marking tasks as unhealthy and
> stopping them before they have time to come up.

if I use like that:

```
aws ecs update-service --region us-east-1 --cluster my-cluster --service my-service --force-new-deployment --health-check-grace-period-seconds 10
```

This is mean the value is "override" the default 300 to the 10 seconds or it change the default to 10 seconds?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

On the screenshot you are marking [deregistration delay](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/load-balancer-target-groups.html#deregistration-delay) which is **different then** [health check grace period](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/service_definition_parameters.html).

> Deregistration delay - By default, Elastic Load Balancing waits **300 seconds** before completing the deregistration process, which can help in-flight requests to the target to complete.

Deregistration delay is a property of your **target group**. Thus if you want to modify it, you should be using [modify-target-group-attributes](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/elbv2/modify-target-group-attributes.html) AWS CLI call.

By default `health check grace period` should be 0. You can check it in console: `Your cluster->Service->Details`:

[image]